# Silverlight and ntp server

Tags: c#, silverlight, ntp

Old Silverlight 4 application.
Some free ntp server (with 123 port).

After google:

- only 4502–4534 ports for WebClient (Silverlight limitation);
- "ProtocolType = Udp" not supported for Webclient (Silverlight limitation).

So question: is it possible send request to ntp server from Silverlight client (in browser)?

Comment: did you tried something

Comment: I got AccessDenied all the time.

Comment: In all google posts: "u got ntp server on 5432 port and ...AccessDenied... okay, use clientaccesspolicy.xml...", so on. In all posts author control both server and client sides. I control only client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have control over the client, then you have a couple of options left:

1. Write an API end point on the server where Silverlight is being hosted and proxy the query via your server.
2. Run the Silverlight application under elevated permissions. There are a lot of steps required. I suggest you have a look at this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg192793(v=vs.95)

Comment: So there is no way to use ntp-server from Silverlight with these requirements (123 port, no server side control)? We have some options for workround. And if so - we use them.

Comment: My understanding is Silverlight was engineered to observe the same security restrictions as a browser would. Hence, no cross origin access.